# How to call two web services for showing tableview header and cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

**I want to show the tableview like the following screen.**

[image]

The tableview contains headers and each header contains different data.
For this specific view data come from two different api calls.

1: First API response like this, this array may be contain many values

```
({

    id = 7162;
    title = student1;
},
{

    id = 7163;
    title = student2;
},)
```

From this response we need to show header section titles like  ( student1 or  student2 )
Then we need to take each id ( e.g.:  id = 7162; ) and call another  web service using these id.

2 : The second web service response like  the following, this array may be contain many values

```
(
     {
       name = “test1”;
    },
    {
       name = “test2”;
    },
)
```

Take all name from this array and show each name under specific tableview header.

I already implemented this like I called two web service in viewDidLoad method.But user need to wait long time for getting all data then only display the data.

I want to know any other method for calling these type of web service?

Comment: there is no other way than that. It should be done on server side, otherways just send this requests in the same time

Comment: The better way is to change in response on server . The other way is to store whole data in to array or dict then reload the tableview. It may take some time to load the page .